# CreateProcess fails when dshow is used in commandline

Tags: c++, winapi, ffmpeg

Trying to launch ffmpeg using CreateProcess.

**Issues:**

1) Can't use `dshow` in the commandline.

2) RTMP streaming with the STDIN piped don't show the stream.

**Questions:**

1) What are the ceveats in the commandline pertaining to CreateProcess api?

2) What's is the way round ? How can the issue be fixed?

This code works:

```
BOOL bSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL,
    L"ffmpeg.exe -y -loop 1 -i kites.jpg  out.mp4",         
    NULL,   
    NULL,
    TRUE, 
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, 
    NULL, 
    NULL,
    &siStartInfo,
    &piProcInfo);
```

CreateProcess fails when `dshow` is used. However it works as command line in console.

```
BOOL bSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL,
    L"ffmpeg.exe -y -loop 1 -i kites.jpg  -f dshow  -i audio=\"Stereo Mix(Realtek High Definition Audio)\"  out.mp4",
    NULL,
    NULL,
    TRUE,
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &siStartInfo,
    &piProcInfo);
```

**Edited:** ( with absolute path, still no luck)

```
std::wstring cmdArgslistSetChannel = L"ffmpeg.exe -y -loop 1 -i c:\test\kites.jpg  -f dshow  -i audio=\"Stereo Mix(Realtek High Definition Audio)\"  out.mp4";
bSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL, 
        &cmdArgslistSetChannel[0],
        NULL,          
        NULL,          
        TRUE,          
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,            
        NULL,          
        NULL,          
        &siStartInfo, 
        &piProcInfo);
```

Comment: Perhaps there is an external dependancy that can't be found because you are not setting a current working directory for the new process, so it inherits the one of the calling process? Try setting an explicit working directory. And consider using "SysInternals Process Monitor" to see exactly which files ffmpeg tries to access and from where.

Comment: Code should never work because the second parameter needs to be a modifiable string.

Comment: From [CreateProcessW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw): *"The Unicode version of this function, `CreateProcessW`, can modify the contents of \[the lpCommandLine\] string. Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a constant string, the function may cause an access violation."*

Comment: I have some questions here, `CreateProcess` fails or ffmpeg command fails? If `CreateProcess` fails, then what's the error code? And What's the bit version of your sample program, 32 or 64? Note that the default console command line is 64-bit. if your sample is in 32-bits, then it may cause the issue by different environment as Remy says.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT: Both system and app are x64. And the command line works from console input.

Comment: You are using a relative path name (`-i kites.jpg`). This requires that your current working directory is the directory you think it is. Relying on the current working directory is inherently unreliable: Any thread can change it at any given time. Use fully qualified path names instead. Always.

Comment: @IInspectable is most likely on spot with the comment about `lpCommandLine` - just tried this with changing the string literal to a proper character array, ffmpeg.exe and kites.jpg in the working directory, worked fine from C++ as well. W/o the array and just using a string literal causes an immediate access violation.

Comment: @ark1974 Well,what's the error code(return by `GetLastError` after `CreateProcess` fails )

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT: Create process returns 1, but console window wasn't created at all . Tried with absolute path as pointed out by `IInspectable` even with a modifiable variable as the command line but no luck. Seems CreateProcess failed to deliver the command line to ffmpeg. Saw similar query under SO but no reply was found. No dshow and all works well. Seems like CreateProcess couldn't link to another process related to direct show.

Comment: Question up for bounty in one day :)

Comment: Have you check Microphone Access of your app? In Settings > Privacy > Microphone

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT: Yes. Live streaming works from the microphone through console command.

Comment: I mean your app but not `ffmpeg`, works in command line only means ffmpeg has the access. BTW, `CreateProcess` return 1 means it actually create a process, but exit immediately. You could use `system("")` instead of `CreateProcess` to get the error message.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT: I have tried with system. It works perfectly. But I need to use CreateProcess to keep the console hidden and use pipes to get/issue instructions to the 'hidden process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195550/discussion-between-drake-wu-msft-and-ark1974).

Comment: I guess you should escape the backslashes in path. `\t` `c:\test` is interpreted as tabulator instead of a backslash...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there. You can specify the absolute path like so. Make sure the no whitespaces are present in the folder name, else ffmpeg command may fail again.  If the `ffmpeg` is situated in another folder, you should specify the path too.

```
std::wstring cmdArgslistSetChannel = L"c:\test\ffmpeg.exe -y -loop 1 -i \"c:\\test\\kites.jpg\"  -f dshow  -i audio=\"Stereo Mix(Realtek High Definition Audio)\"  out.mp4";
```

Answer (score 1):

**First,**

The immediate issue is simply that you need to escape backslashes.

Change:

```
c:\test\kites.jpg
```

*To*

```
c:\\test\\kites.jpg
```

*'\t' is a tab and '\' is a backslash*

**Second,**

from [Comment](http://%20Jun%2025%20at%207:30):

> From CreateProcessW: *"The Unicode version of this function,
>   CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of [the lpCommandLine] string.
>   Therefore, this parameter cannot be a pointer to read-only memory
>   (such as a const variable or a literal string). If this parameter is a
>   constant string, the function may cause an access violation."*

Therefore you need to hold the contents in a buffer like this:

```
std::wstring args{L"c:\test\ffmpeg.exe -y -loop 1 -i \"c:\\test\\kites.jpg\"  -f dshow  -i audio=\"Stereo Mix(Realtek High Definition Audio)\"  out.mp4"};
```

**Third,**

if you know full path to the executable (which it seems), you can benefit from putting that into the first parameter of [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) instead. This will give you a little more control and diagnostics (in the future as well) as it is a more direct way of creating the process.